# Python print with multiple arguments vs printing an fstring

Tags: python, python-3.x, f-string

Is there an unspoken rule, or a PEP rule that says that it's better to use an f string when printing something to the screen rather than using print with multiple arguments?
Example:

```
age = 80
name = "John"
print(f'My name is {name} and I am {age} years old')
print('My name is', name, 'and I am', age, 'years old')
```

I was trying to explain to someone that f-string are more used, but he kept insisting that the second option is easier. Both examples will work, I am just curious if there is a rule that suggests using f strings, or why is it bad practice to use print with multiple arguments.

Thanks

Comment: Python f-strings only exist since 3.6, so saying that they are more used doesn't seem to be very realistic. I didn't find anything in PEP8 about print. What can be argued though is that printing using multiple arguments is kinda unique to the print function, when using f-strings can help make uniform string building across a code base.

Comment: i also prefer 2nd method

Comment: Why do you think one option is preferred? They both work, they're both similarly readable. f-strings didn't even exist until recently (3.6+), so there's definitely no history favoring them.

Comment: When I was talking about more used I meant in newer projects. And when I said it is the preferred one I did it because from my experience and the people I interacted with f strings seemed to be the preferred way.

Answer (score 2):

In the presented example there is no real difference. However, while working with strings you sometimes need to create a "parametric" string: in such a case you will be obliged to use [`f-string`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting), [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#the-string-format-method) method or the [old-style](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#old-string-formatting) string formatting. Which one to use if mostly depend on your preferences and your application (for example, sometimes you are blocked with an older version of Python).

These will work:

```
name = 'Johnny'
age = 18

# old-style
s1 = 'My name is %s and I am %s years old' % (name, age)

# format()
s2 = 'My name is {0} and I am {1} years old'.format(name, age)

# f-string
s3 = f'My name is {name} and I am {age} years old'
```

> You can see it as an evolution s1 --> s2 --> s3 (so more modern - more developed)

While these **would not** work as expected

```
# This will give a tuple
s4 = 'My name is', name, 'and I am', age, 'years old'

# This will throw an exception as the age is of the `int` type
s5 = 'My name is' + name + 'and I am' + age + 'years old'
```

We could also add that some [nice features](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) are accessible with string formatting (s1, s2 and s3) and not accessible with `print(a, b, c)`.

Answer (score 1):

I should preface this by saying that *I personally prefer* using f-strings, and therefore my answer might be biased towards using it.
However, I think there is at least one clear advantage of using f-strings over the multiple arguments, which is that **f-strings are strings**.

This might seem like an obvious observation, but it means that any manipulation operation that I perform with f-strings can be directly translated into a singular statement outside of `print()` as well. The second approach, however, utilizes multiple arguments, which is not something that I can package into a separate statement.
IMO, this makes refactoring outputs much easier, since you can simply copy+paste code from print statements to somewhere else and maintain consistency in your code styling.

Another point is the performance of f-strings. While I haven't seen explicit comparisons to multi-argument `print()`s, there is a bunch of posts comparing f-strings to the other methods (e.g., here [https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#speed]). In a quick experiment I did myself with `timeit`, i found the following:

```py
import timeit
y = David
x = Dan
timeit.timeit("print(f'My name is {y} {x}')", setup="from __main__ import x,y", number=1000000)
# 4.74 s

timeit.timeit("print('My name is', y, x)", setup="from __main__ import x,y", number=1000000)
# 5.72 s
```

Of course, speed for print statements is usually not so crucial that it matters, but might just be another argument.